# numpy broadcasting boolean indexes

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

How to re-write this python loop using numpy broadcasting?

```
>>> values.shape
(50000,)
>>> tests.shape  # booleans
(200, 50000)

>>> extracted = values[tests]
# FAILES

>>> extracted = values[test] for test in tests]
>>> extracted.shape
(200,)
>>> extracted[0].shape
(33,)
>>> extracted[1].shape
(468,)
```

Fancy/boolean indexing doesn't work here as usual.

Comment: And you want `extracted` as 1D concatenated array of length `200 + 33 + 468 + ...` or as something else?

Comment: A flat array doesn't work for me. I need to know how many values for test_1, test_2, etc.

Comment: End result will be percentile matrix/vector. That already works but I want to use numpy to speed up the loopings.

Comment: So, would it be a list of arrays that have different sizes?

Comment: Yes, I hoped to visualize that by (33,) and (468,). But if there's a better solution?

Comment: I would say stick to that list comprehension solution.

Answer (score 0):

how about this way?
if you just want to get size of each rows quickly.

```
>>> values.shape
(50000,)
>>> tests.shape  # booleans
(200, 50000)

>>> extracted = np.prod((tests,values))
>>> extracted.shape
(200,50000)
>>> rows, cols = extracted.nonzero()
>>> cols[rows==0].shape
(33,)
>>> cols[rows==1].shape
(468,)
```